# How to call automatically symbolic variables in a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Is there anyway to use a loop index to call symbolic variables in Matlab? For example, consider the following code whose goal is to store the symbolic expression "x1+x2+x3" in "y".

```
syms x1 x2 x3
y = 0;

for i = 1:3
    y = y + xi;
end
```

The code does not work because on each iteration Matlab reads "y = y + xi" and returns the error "xi is undefined", instead of reading "y = y + x1", "y = y + x2" and "y = y + x3", is there anyway around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *Matlab* does not support the matrix declaration of symbolics directly (as `sym('x',[3 1])`) you can write your own function for that:

```
function out = Matrix_Sym(name, size) %#ok<STOUT>

rows = size(1);
cols = size(2);

S = '';
for k1 = 1:rows
    for k2 = 1:cols
        if rows == 1
            S = [S name int2str(k2) ' '];
        elseif cols == 1
            S = [S name int2str(k1) ' '];
        else
            S = [S name int2str(k1) int2str(k2) ' '];
        end
    end
end

eval(['syms ' S]);

eval (['out = reshape([' S '], [rows, cols]);']);
```

Then you could get the same result with:

```
x = Matrix_Sym('x', [3 1])
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest this, provided that you can create your numbered symbolic variable slightly differently:

```
x = sym('x',[1 3]);  % or: syms x1 x2 x3; x = [x1 x2 x3];
y = x(1);
for i = 2:numel(x)
    y = y+x(i);
end
```

Of course in this simple example, the entire `for` loop and everything else can be replaced with:

```
y = sum(sym('x',[1 3]));
```

See the documentation on [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) for more details.

**EDIT**: Note that, as @pm89 points out, by allocating the 1-by-3 symbolic vector `x`, you of course won't have direct access to the symbolic variables `x1`,`x2`, and `x3` in your workspace, but will have to index them as shown. This is similar to working with arrays or cells and has many of the same benefits as my second vectorized example illustrates.

Comment: +1: In the first case (`sym('x',[1 3])`), it might worth mentioning that `x1` would be undefined if used by itself and has to be accessed with `x(1)`.

Comment: +1: However, say I cannot declare arrays of symbols, any suggestions then? I'm actually not using the standard Matlab symbolic objects - I'm using some custom symbolic objects that represent polynomials (which are part of [this open source toolbox](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/sostools/), which mentions little about what to do with the above in its documentation). However, for the most part (except being able to declare arrays of these symbols) the objects behave as normal matlab symbolic variables do.

Comment: @jkn: Please edit your question then. If the objects you describe are not class `sym` then I think that it's a bit misleading to ask about `syms` and use `syms` in your example. Are these custom objects strings? Do they have an associated `eval` function?